# JQuery get value of checkbox only if checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

At the moment I am using the following bit of code to only get the values of checked checkboxes, however I am sure that there is an easier way that this.

```
if ($('#OPTtags-adventure-diving').is(':checked')) {
        var OPTtags-adventure-diving = $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving').val()
    } else var OPTtags-adventure-diving = '';

    if ($('#OPTtags-master-scuba-diver').is(':checked')) {
        var OPTtags-master-scuba-diver = $('#OPTtags-master-scuba-diver').val()
    } else var OPTtags-master-scuba-diver = '';
```

Is there?

Marvellous,

Comment: Minor point: variable names with hypens are illegal in JS. The problem is that `OPTtags-adventure-diving` could be interpreted as `OPTtags` minus `adventure` minus `diving`. Better  to use camelCase or underscore.

Comment: @johnhunter Point taken,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not checked this, but how about

`var OPTtags-master-scuba-diver = $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving:checked').val()`

Then your variable will be `undefined` or the value.

Comment: Do not overlook the subtle (though mentioned by Chris) fact that this will return "undefined" when the checkbox isn't checked.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit simpler:

```
var OPTtags-adventure-diving = $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving:checked').length ? $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving').val() : '';
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/SfcjG/

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
var $chkbox = $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving'),
    OPTtags-adventure-diving = $chkbox.is(':checked') ? $chkbox.val() : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var OPTtags-master-scuba-diver = $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving:checked').val() || '':
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#OPTtags-adventure-diving').prop('checked') ? $('#OPTtags-adventure-diving').val() : ''
```